# How can I decide the priority between media queries and css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a page.css used from the master page to others pages.
In that file I have a property for a div: `<div class="classDivOne">Hello</div>`
that is:

```
.classDivOne{
margin-top:5px;
}
```

Now, with windows explorer everything is fine.

Instead with Chrome I need to fix `margin-top:0px;`.

I used media queries (inside master page) in this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        .classDivOne{
            margin-top:0px;
        }
   }
</style>
```

but I noted that the file css is the primary choice and my media screen for chrome is not used. If I put into the div `style="margin-top:0px"` I have the same result.

How can I set the priority into the choice of css for that div?
Or there is a different solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this for modern versions of IE. For older versions, you could use IE-only conditional comments.

Comment: do you want to target specific browser? or you want to prioritize one css property over another?

Comment: It's working http://jsfiddle.net/fKgmR/1/ please show us not working fiddle.

Comment: I used a class inside css for that div. It is used from all browsers. I noted that only in chrome that property makes a different output, so I need to say "when is used chrome use a different margin-top". To do that I used media queries, but the browser still set the margin-top in che css standard. Why?I'm sure that media queries works because with others attributes not defined in classDivOne it works!

Comment: While SO is about people asking questions and others providing answers, serving as a records to help others as well, simply providing an answer to this is, to me, not in the best interests of the OP **nor** anybody else stumbling across this. The correct answer should be: **STOP** what you are doing. **READ** tutorials on how to write HTML and CSS better. **START** again. The exact answer to your question may solve your issue for now, but it is shooting yourself in the foot to prevent your back from hurting. It is doing anybody who reads this, looking for advice, a huge disservice.

Comment: I already read tutorials about css or html.It is impossible to know everything if I handle with something not standard or with base things.In this case,what I thought(and it was obvious for me)it was that If I specify a property in media queries,they had to execute for sure those properties overwriting the css.With this solution,in my opinion is interesting not that I can use "!important" but understand how media queries and css interact.That can help me in many cases,and I think a lot of people not genius like you believe to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this way

```
<style type="text/css">
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        .classDivOne.classDivOne{
            margin-top:0px;
        }
   }
</style>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        .classDivOne{
            margin-top:0px !important;
        }
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
<style type="text/css">
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        .classDivOne{
            margin-top:0px !important;
        }
   }
</style>


! important
```

is used to make the priority of property higher than other.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 0),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 0),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 0dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 0px) { 

  .classDivOne{
            margin-top:0px !important;
        }

}

/*OR*/

@media screen and/*!*/(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
        .classDivOne{
            margin-top:0px !important;
        }

 }
</style>
```